# Center of mass of $x^2+y^2 \leq z \leq h$

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

I'm trying to find the center of mass of this shape $x^2+y^2 \leq z \leq h$but im having difficulties founding the limits of integration.

using cylindrical coordinates, $x=rcos \theta$, $y=r \sin \theta$

I would suspect that since $0\leq x^2+y^2 \leq z \leq h$, then $0 \leq r \leq \sqrt{h}$, and $r^2 \leq z \leq h$ and the jacobian is $r$.

But the integral $$M=\int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{\sqrt{h}} \int_{r^2}^{h}r dzdrd\theta = \frac{\pi h^2}{2}$$

That is the mass of this shape.

Now let's find the moment in the $xy$ direction:

$$M_{xy} = \int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{\sqrt{h}} \int_{r^2}^{h}rz dzdrd\theta =\frac{\pi h^3}{3}$$

So the $z$ coordinate at the center of mass should be:

$$z_{cm}=\frac{M_{xy}}{M}=\frac{2}{3}h$$

but the answer given in the worksheet says $z_{cm}=\frac{3}{4}h$

Where am I mistaken? I'm sure it's the integration domain. But why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say that you have counted correctly. Z coordinate of the center of mass is $\frac{2}{3}h$:

$dM=\pi(x^2+y^2)\,dz=\pi z\,dz\,\Rightarrow \,M=\pi\int_0^hdM=\pi\int_0^hz\,dz=\pi[\frac{z^2}{2}]_0^h=\pi\frac{h^2}{2}$

$dM_{xy}=z\pi(x^2+y^2)\,dz=\pi z^2\,dz\,\Rightarrow \, M_{xy}=\pi\int_0^hz^2\,dz=\pi[\frac{z^3}{3}]_0^h=\pi\frac{h^3}{3}$

$\Rightarrow \,z_{cm}=\frac{2}{3}h$

Result in the worksheet $\left(\frac{3}{4}h \right)$ is not correct. To find also in a collection of mathematical formulas.

Comment: It is unlikely that $M = k h^2$ - as mass would be proportional to volume with uniform density, i.e. $M = k h^3$...

The worksheet result $\tfrac{3}{4} h$ is correct in my opinion...

Comment: But it also likely in this case... ;)

Comment: @johannesvalks: For each rotational paraboloid with a constant density = c: $M=c\cdot \frac{1}{2}\pi r_{max}^2h=c\cdot \frac{1}{2}\pi h^2=k\cdot h^2$

Comment: Yes - I already replied that...

Answer (score 0):

Everything is fine with the calculation. An alternative parametrization is 
$M_{xy}=\int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{h} \int_{0}^{\sqrt{z}}r~\mathrm dr~\mathrm dz~\mathrm d\theta =2\pi\frac{h^2}{2}$ and 
$M_{xy}=\int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{h} \int_{0}^{\sqrt{z}}rz~\mathrm dr~\mathrm dz~\mathrm d\theta =2\pi\frac{h^3}{6}$.

Comment: I understand why $0 < z< h$, i understand, but why $r <z$? we know that $x^2+y^2 =r^2 <z$, so if anything $r <\sqrt{z}$ no?

Comment: you're right. I've redone my calculation and got the same answer as you did, so in indeed your worksheet is probably incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Given

$$
x^2 + y^2 \le z \le h
$$

Then consider cylinder co-ordinates

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
x &=& r \cos(\phi)\\
y &=& r \sin(\phi)\\
z &=& z
\end{eqnarray}
$$

Then you obtain

$$
\iiint_V dx dy dz \Psi = \int_0^h dz \int_0^\sqrt{z} dr \int_0^{2\pi} d\phi r \Psi
$$

So the volume $(\Psi=1)$ is simply given by

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
V &=& \int_0^h dz \int_0^\sqrt{z} dr \int_0^{2\pi} d\phi r\\
&=& 2 \pi \int_0^h dz \int_0^\sqrt{z} dr r\\
&=& \pi \int_0^h dz z\\
&=& \frac{\pi h^2}{2}
\end{eqnarray}
$$

Uniform density implies that we have

$$
\langle \Psi \rangle = \frac{2}{\pi h^2} \int_0^h dz \int_0^\sqrt{z} dr \int_0^{2\pi} d\phi r \Psi
$$

and for center of mass we obtain

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
\langle \Psi_x \rangle &=& \frac{2}{\pi h^2} \int_0^h dz \int_0^\sqrt{z} dr \int_0^{2\pi} d\phi r r \cos(\phi)\\
\langle \Psi_y \rangle &=& \frac{2}{\pi h^2} \int_0^h dz \int_0^\sqrt{z} dr \int_0^{2\pi} d\phi r r \sin(\phi)\\
\langle \Psi_z \rangle &=& \frac{2}{\pi h^2} \int_0^h dz \int_0^\sqrt{z} dr \int_0^{2\pi} d\phi r z
\end{eqnarray}
$$

So it is clear that

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
\langle \Psi_x \rangle &=& 0\\
\langle \Psi_y \rangle &=& 0
\end{eqnarray}
$$

and

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
\langle \Psi_x \rangle &=& \frac{2}{\pi h^2} \int_0^h dz \int_0^\sqrt{z} dr r z\\
&=& \frac{2}{h^2} \int_0^h dz z^2\\
&=& \frac{2}{3} h
\end{eqnarray}
$$

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not sure I agree Johannesvalks. You wrote $\int_{0}^{z}dr$, but again, $x^2+y^2 < z$ implies $r^2 <z$, not $r<z$. so saying $r$ goes from 0 to $z$ is false.

Comment: Yep - small errors are easy to make...

Comment: Then you agree that the correct is answer is $\frac{2}{3} \pi$?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to show its $\frac{2}{3}h$ in another way.

Realize that $x^2+y^2 <z$ in a 2d plane represents a circle with $\sqrt{z}$ radius.

Let's call that circle $A$.

We are asked to calculate $\int_{0}^{h} \iint_A dxdy dz$ (Fubini shows us that order of integration does not matter)

however, $\iint_A dxdy$ is merely the area of $A$, which is according to formula for area of circle, $\pi z$.

So the integral for the mass is $\int_{0}^{h} \pi zdz=\frac{\pi h^2}{2}$

With a similar argument, you can see that $M_{xy}=\frac{\pi h^3}{3}$ and as such, $z_{cm}=\frac{2}{3}h$

Comment: Yes. $z_ {cm} = \frac{2}{3} h$ is correct for each rotational paraboloid with a constant density.